# Simple question about Registry CreateSubKey

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

Why doesn't this work? I am trying to create a registry key under [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyService], but nothing is created.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace RegistryKey
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string SUB_KEY_NAME = @"SOFTWARE\MyService";

            // Create a subkey named MyService under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
            Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(SUB_KEY_NAME);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** Never mind. I'm an idiot. I used the Remote registry Editor to inspect the registry in the belief that it would show the same as regedit. It didn't! I can see the path using regedit.

Comment: I assume you aren't getting an exception when that code executes?

Comment: That is correct. No exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have write access to HKLM. If you want to write here then you need to either:

- run the process as an elevated user, or.
- only attempt to write to HKLM during install.

Comment: You should totally get a `SecurityException` if this is the case. That's why I asked the question initially. Strange, though I agree completely with this answer.

Comment: @Cody Sorry if I stole your thunder, but this advice is just so fundamental I didn't bother to wait or try to understand exactly what's going on with original problem. As you yourself have said, such problems are solved this way 99.9% of the time!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
RegistryKey regkey = Registry.CurrentUser;
regkey = regkey.CreateSubKey(SUB_KEY_NAME); //this is the path then you create yours keys
regkey.SetValue("Install", "ok"); //name of key exp:(install) and then the value exp:(ok)
```